# How to upgrade Django on ubuntu?

Tags: django, ubuntu

Not a Django developer. We initially installed Django from Ubuntu packages by typing `apt-get install python-django`. Now we need version 1.x - our version is 0.96.1 Could you advise an easy way to upgrade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really can't upgrade the Ubuntu package as suggested by Ludwik, you might want to consider installing the source directly. It's pretty easy, and is [fully documented here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/install/#installing-official-release).

Answer (score 66):

Easiest way to upgrade Django on Ububtu is to make use of the `easy_install` script provided by the `python-setuptools` package.

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install --upgrade django
```

Comment: I tried 'sudo pip install -U django' to ugrade from 1.3 to 1.4 and that did not work. 'easy_install' worked.

Answer (score 4):

One of the way is typing this command on console:

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've got a really old version of Ubuntu. Django 0.96.1 was distributed last time with Ubuntu 8.04. Official repositories for the most recent Ubuntu 9.10 includes Django 1.1.1, which is the most recent version of Django. You can upgrade Ubuntu or try to install [the new .deb package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/python-django) in your old OS (although I can't promise that all dependencies will be met by Ubuntu 8.04).